# Javascript promise implementation

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

Whats best way to implement below in javascript.

```
/*
  A --|
      |-- D --|
  B --|       |-- E
              |
  C ----------|
```

Each node is a async job, illustrated by `setTimeout`.

A, B, and C can run at the same time.

D, needs to wait for A and B to be done.

E needs to wait for C and D to be done.

How can I implement an interface which accepts the above nodes as args, which would take care of above implementation. Not sure what's best to implement whether `async`/`await` or JavaScript promise can be used and pros/cons.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class `Task` you could use. When you create one, you need to provide it with a name, an asynchronous function (that will be called when the task can start), and a list of other task instances on which this task is dependent:

```js
class Task {
    constructor(name, asyncWork, ...neededTasks) {
        this.promise = (async () => {
            await Promise.all(neededTasks.map(task => task.promise));
            console.log("start " + name);
            await asyncWork();
            console.log("complete " + name);
        })();
    }
}

// Utility function to mimic some asynchronous work, using setTimeout:
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

// Define the tasks. Note that they will automatically call 
// the given function if there are no other tasks to wait for:
let a = new Task("a", () => delay(1000));
let b = new Task("b", () => delay(1500));
let c = new Task("c", () => delay(2000));
let d = new Task("d", () => delay(1000), a, b);
let e = new Task("e", () => delay(1000), c, d);
```

When a task is created, a promise is created for it. It is stored in its `promise` property. This promise will only resolve when:

- the "predecessor" promises, created for the tasks it is dependent on, are resolved
- the actual asynchronous work for this task has run to completion (i.e. its returned promise has resolved)

These two steps are chained, so the actual work will not commence before the promises of the first step have resolved.

Answer (score -3):

```js
        /*
          A --|
             |-- D --|
        B --|       |-- E
                   |
      C ----------|
        */
        let A = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve("im from A");
            }, 0);
        });
        let B = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve("im from B");
            }, 0);
        });
        let C = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve("im from C");
            }, 0);
        });
        let D = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve("im from D");
            }, 0);
        });
        let E = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve("im from E");
            }, 0);
        });

        (async () => {
            let [stringOfA, stringOfB] = await Promise.all([A, B]);
            let [stringOfD, stringOfC] = await Promise.all([D, C]);
            let stringOfE = await E;
            console.log(stringOfA, stringOfB, stringOfC, stringOfD, stringOfE);
        })();
```

Comment: You launch all tasks immediately.

Comment: C waits for A and B instead of running concurrently. Also, you're expected to explain what the answer does, not just dump some code.